# Not able to push new object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex, javascript-objects

getting below error

*state.products.push is not a function*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const URL =  "http://localhost:3000/products"
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: [],
    success: null,
    error: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setAllProducts(state,payload){
      state.products =  payload
    },
    createAProduct(state, payload) {
      const newProduct = payload
      console.log(typeof state.products)
      console.log(state)
      state.products.push(newProduct)
      
    },
    setSuccess (state , payload) {
      state.success = payload
    }, 
    setError (state, payload) {
      state.error = payload
    },
    updateAProduct(state,payload) {
      for( let product in state.products)
      {
        if(product.id == payload[1])
        {
        product.productName=  payload[0].productName,
        product.productDescription =  payload[0].productDescription,
        product.manufacturer =  payload[0].manufacturer,
        product.price = payload[0].price,
        product.quantity = payload[0].quantity
        }
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addNewProduct({ commit }, payload) {
      const product = {
        productName: payload.productName,
        productDescription: payload.productDescription,
        manufacturer: payload.manufacturer,
        price: payload.price,
        quantity: payload.quantity,
      }
      axios.post(`${URL}`, product)
      .then((data) =>{
        let key =  data.id
        commit('createAProduct',{...product,key})
        commit('setSuccess', `${data.data.productName} is added to Products` )
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.log(error)
        commit('setError', error )
      }
      )
    },
    updateProduct({commit}, payload)
    {
      const product =  {
        productName: payload[0].productName,
        productDescription: payload[0].productDescription,
        manufacturer: payload[0].manufacturer,
        price: payload[0].price,
        quantity: payload[0].quantity,
      }
      axios.put(`${URL}/${payload[1]}`,product)
      .then((data)=>{
        commit('updateAProduct', payload)
        commit('setSuccess', `${data.data.productName} is updated successfully` )
      })
      
    },
    addAllProducts( {commit }, payload)
    {
      commit('setAllProducts',payload)
    }
  },
  getters:{
    success (state) {
            return state.success
        },
        error (state) {
            return state.error
        }
  }

})
```

Payload has below properties

key: 12
manufacturer: "H & M"
price: "12"
productDescription: "JAvascript t-shirt by H & M"
productName: "Deepraj maurya"
quantity: "12"

Added whole index.js file, Please have a look. I am just creating and updating a product

addAllProducts is called by below method:

```
 getAllProducts() {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/products`)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(typeof data)
          console.log(data)

          this.$store.dispatch("addAllProducts", data);
        });
```

Comment: Define *"not able"*. what you are saying is impossible so its logical this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Is it OK  now please help out

Comment: I assume you are using vuex. What is state before calling state.products.push ?

Comment: Yes I am using Vuex, type of state.products is showing object, Is it possible, it should be array right?

Comment: typeof of an array prints object. You should just console.log(state.products) (for culture you can use Array.isArray). I would hint that products is not even a variable of your state and you miscopied your code snippet or something (hence the importance of **minimal reproducible example**)

Comment: products is there ` added in question

Comment: object will not have .push method, I think that's why this error is happening, then how can I fix it?

Comment: as per what you provided this should be ok. What is left is for you (so we don't guess &try) is to provide the minimal reproducible example. E.g are we sure you are not using vuex-persist with a products being sthg other than array, are we sure you did not assign an object to products instead at some point..

Comment: added whole code @grodzi, Please let me know, other functionalities are working fine

Comment: who is calling addAllProducts ? and with what as payload (ensure it is an array):
if (e.g) you are passing the payload from axios you have to be sure you are taking the value associated to data ```(axios...then(({data}) => commit('setAllProducts', data))```

Comment: I checked data is coming as type object , how can convert it to array

Comment: added the method in question from  which addAllmethods is called

Comment: can you share  console.log(data) - value form axios call ? (and in javascript typeof for array will return object ). you can use ---  Array.isArray --- to check if data is of type array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatch the data.products

getAllProducts() {
axios .get(http://localhost:3000/products)
.then((data) => {
console.log(typeof data)
console.log(data)
this.$store.dispatch("addAllProducts", data.products);
});.